# Display text (flexbox) when hover over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hover over the rotating circle to display the 4 "about" texts. But the issue is that I am using flexbox and when I enter the cursor into the area covered by flex, it displays the text, but I want it to only appear when hovering over the rotating circle. I think the issue is due to overlapping. You can see the demo of the issue here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74Qzns1ooOI

My HTML code is below:

```css
.main .some-page-wrapper p {
  opacity: 0;
}

.main:hover .some-page-wrapper p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main img:hover {
  width: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.some-page-wrapper {
  /* background-color: red; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flex-basis: 100%; */
  flex: 1;
}

.orange-column {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'hermes';
  font-size: 50px;
  /* background-color: orange; */
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blue-column {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'hermes';
  font-size: 50px;
  /* background-color: blue; */
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.green-column {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'hermes';
  font-size: 50px;
  /* background-color: green; */
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img class="dp" src="assets/logo.png">
  <div class='some-page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <div class='orange-column'>
          <p>About</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <div class='blue-column'>
          <p>About</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column'>
        <div class='green-column'>
          <p>About</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <div class='orange-column'>
          <p>About</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so to be sure you want the class ```row``` to only be visible when hovered on class ```.main img``` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with overlapping as you mentioned. You need to put your image in front and activate the `:hover` only on the `<img>` element, not on the wrap.

Here is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/Martin_levai/pen/abqdbzx).

In short:

- `<img>` has `position: absolute` and is centered so the columns are "in background"
- the hover activates only on `<img>` tag and targets `<p>` element in sibling element with the `+` selector.

Comment: How do I add a functionality such that when the user clicks after hovering over the image, the texts remain there and when clicked anywhere outside, it disappears? I assume we should use JS for this?

Comment: Yep, for click events youu need to use JS. You will need to create a [click event](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) and inside of it check the position of the current click location. Based on that you change the styles of your elements either directly with JS or you just replace some class with JS.

Comment: I tried doing it but it doesn't work. I could successfully test the background color change. I used this code - onclick="var s= document.getElementById('logo'); s.style.opacity='1';". Can you add your code in your codepen working demo which you linked?

Comment: I would suggest you to look for the answer in existing questions or create a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the box sizing of your image is quite a lot wider than you expect, causing your hover to activate before the cursor touches the visible image border.

If so, you can round its borders into a cirle via `border-radius`:

```
img.dp {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```